# Android progress dialog while getting data from sqlite

Tags: android, multithreading, json, http-post, progressdialog

I tried to implement threads, asynctask from examples on the web but none of them run the way I want.

I have a class to send data to a web server.
It contains 3 tasks:
-grab an id 
-get data from sql and build a json file
-send the json file

I'd like to implement a progress dialog or progressbar to show progress to the user waiting.

The progressdialog I last tested to show data grabbing from sqlite was based on [Progress Bar Example](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html).
Trouble is that when I try to generate my file more than 2 times, the thread is not starting...

So whats's the best to be done in my case ?
I have a spinner to select what to send and a button to send.

When button is clicked, basically I have:

```
HttpResponse response = GetChantier(commentaire);
    //Checking response 
    if( response != null)
    {
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        int chantier_serveur = Integer.parseInt(_response.replaceAll("[\n\r]", ""))
        String fichier = DonneesToJson(db,chantier, chantier_serveur);
        HttpResponse response = SendJson ( chantier, fichier);
    }
```

I'd need to implement a progress for DonneesToJson and SendJson.

DonnesToJson grabs a cursor then build a json file while iterating the cursor.
SendJson is an HttpPost that sends a file and 2 fields.

I'm really new to java programming and threads.
Any help appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: use asynctask and invoke progressDialog in preExecute function.

Comment: how do I pass my args in asynctask ?

Comment: asynctask is similar to class, so make a constructor for it and initialize the fields in it using it.

Comment: @Cedric Check my updated answer.Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Async task for doing Background task as follows.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    new Asyn_Task().execute("name","title");
}


class Asyn_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Facebook_Post_View.this);
    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    name=params[0]; //Like
                    title=params[1];

         // Do your all Stuffs
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

In these at **position 0** name will available and at **position 1** title will available.Similarly you can pass values as you like..

For further reference check this [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks Venky.
This helped a lot and when I understood how AsyncTask works and how to chain them, works great !!
I am adding errors treatments now and all looks good.